# IntelliJ Idea 15 hangs when starting and debuging

Tags: performance, networking, intellij-idea, freeze

this is my first question.
I'm confusing on my IntelliJ Idea hanging 1 minute when starting and debugging with network on. Could anyone help me? Thanks.
I have tried IntelliJC and IntelliJU which are both 15.0.4. When I cut down the network, It works with no problem. But, with network on, it becomes hanging when starting and debugging.
Through logs, I found that there's almost 1 minute between I starting IntelliJ and its log beginning.
I even captured its network packets, found nothing, there was no connection.

I'm using Macbook, and I found the system log:

```
Mar 11 07:49:36 Coderec's MBP idea[1867]: Value of IDEA_JDK: (null)
Mar 11 07:49:36 Coderec's MBP idea[1867]: fullFileName is: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
Mar 11 07:49:36 Coderec's MBP idea[1867]: fullFileName exists: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
Mar 11 07:49:36 Coderec's MBP idea[1867]: Value of IDEA_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
Mar 11 07:49:36 Coderec's MBP idea[1867]: Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
Mar 11 07:49:36 Coderec's MBP idea[1867]: Done
```

and the IntelliJ log:

```
2016-03-11 07:50:37,529 [  60385]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2016-03-11 07:50:37,559 [  60415]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IC-143.2287.1, 23 Feb 2016 00:00) 
2016-03-11 07:50:37,559 [  60415]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Mac OS X (10.11.3, x86_64) 
2016-03-11 07:50:37,559 [  60415]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_40-release-b132 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2016-03-11 07:50:37,559 [  60415]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.40-b25 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2016-03-11 07:50:37,560 [  60416]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Xverify:none -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions -Didea.java.redist=custom-jdk-bundled -Didea.home.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents -Didea.executable=idea -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC15 
2016-03-11 07:50:37,561 [  60417]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext: [cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, jfxrt.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2016-03-11 07:50:37,561 [  60417]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: /System/Library/Java/Extensions: [MRJToolkit.jar] 
2016-03-11 07:50:37,581 [  60437]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 20 ms 
2016-03-11 07:50:37,584 [  60440]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - initializing environment 
2016-03-11 07:50:37,585 [  60441]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - loading shell env: /bin/zsh -l -i -c '/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/bin/printenv.py' '/private/var/folders/w9/rkmh4kqs2l3bd5nf5mlp7k100000gq/T/intellij-shell-env.0.tmp' 
2016-03-11 07:50:38,546 [  61402]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - shell environment loaded (19 vars) 
2016-03-11 07:50:38,784 [  61640]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2016-03-11 07:50:39,050 [  61906]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 31 plugins initialized in 436 ms 
2016-03-11 07:50:39,052 [  61908]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.1.3.0), Ant Support (1.0), Bytecode Viewer (0.1), CVS Integration (11), Copyright (8.1), Coverage (143.SNAPSHOT), Eclipse Integration (3.0), EditorConfig (1.0), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (143.2287.1), Gradle (143.2287.1), Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java (143.2287.1), IDEA CORE (143.SNAPSHOT), IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (0.1), JavaFX (1.0), Kotlin (1.0.0-release-IJ143-75), Maven Integration (143.2287.1), Plugin DevKit (1.0), Properties Support (143.SNAPSHOT), Settings Repository (143.2287.1), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), UI Designer (143.2287.1), XPathView + XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger (1.4), hg4idea (10.0) 
2016-03-11 07:50:39,384 [  62240]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=739246080 
2016-03-11 07:50:39,415 [  62271]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/bin/fsnotifier 
2016-03-11 07:50:39,423 [  62279]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2016-03-11 07:50:40,025 [  62881]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2016-03-11 07:50:40,564 [  63420]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 84 application components initialized in 1951 ms 
2016-03-11 07:50:40,581 [  63437]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 63756 ms 
2016-03-11 07:50:40,588 [  63444]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - <html>You have JVM property "socksProxyHost" set to "127.0.0.1".<br>This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy<br>This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.<br>(Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.) 
2016-03-11 07:50:40,647 [  63503]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - <html>You have JVM property "socksProxyHost" set to "127.0.0.1".<br>This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy<br>This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.<br>(Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.) 
2016-03-11 07:50:41,176 [  64032]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 8 
2016-03-11 07:50:41,575 [  64431]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 148 project components initialized in 746 ms 
2016-03-11 07:50:41,723 [  64579]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 2 module(s) loaded in 147 ms 
2016-03-11 07:50:43,450 [  66306]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - /Users/coderec/IdeaProjects/pttms-server/pttms-server/.idea/misc.xml case-sensitivity: false 
2016-03-11 07:50:44,351 [  67207]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 22ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2016-03-11 07:50:44,934 [  67790]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 4133 ms 
2016-03-11 07:50:45,903 [  68759]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 1551ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2016-03-11 07:50:46,373 [  69229]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
2016-03-11 07:50:47,309 [  70165]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2016-03-11 07:50:47,678 [  70534]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java" -d64 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Didea.version==15.0.4 -Xmx512m -Didea.maven.embedder.version=3.0.5 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/resources_en.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/jna-platform.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/snappy-in-java-0.3.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/picocontainer.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/jna.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/oromatcher.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/annotations.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/jdom.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/lucene-core-2.4.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven-server-api.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3-server-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3-server-lib/archetype-catalog-2.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3-server-lib/archetype-common-2.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3-server-lib/maven-dependency-tree-1.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3-server-lib/nexus-indexer-3.0.4.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3-server-lib/nexus-indexer-artifact-1.0.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven30-server-impl.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/aether-api-1.13.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/aether-connector-wagon-1.13.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/aether-impl-1.13.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/aether-spi-1.13.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/aether-util-1.13.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.0.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-artifact-3.0.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-compat-3.0.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-core-3.0.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-embedder-3.0.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-3.0.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-builder-3.0.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.0.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.0.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-settings-3.0.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.0.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/sisu-inject-bean-2.3.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/sisu-inject-plexus-2.3.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-file-2.8.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-http-2.8-shaded.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-http-shared-2.8.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-provider-api-2.8.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar" org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer 
2016-03-11 07:50:47,917 [  70773]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Port/ID: 4823/Maven30ServerImplf51fe04a 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,891 [  71747]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 0 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG Sisu  - Add publisher: com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl@5fd5172c 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,891 [  71747]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -  
2016-03-11 07:50:48,891 [  71747]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - -----[explicit bindings]------------------------------------------------------- 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,891 [  71747]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 0. ProviderInstanceBinding{key=Key[type=com.google.inject.Injector, annotation=[none]], source=[unknown source], scope=Scopes.NO_SCOPE, provider=Provider<Injector>} 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,891 [  71747]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 1. ProviderInstanceBinding{key=Key[type=java.util.logging.Logger, annotation=[none]], source=[unknown source], scope=Scopes.NO_SCOPE, provider=Provider<Logger>} 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,891 [  71747]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 2. ProviderInstanceBinding{key=Key[type=org.slf4j.Logger, annotation=[none]], source=[unknown source], scope=Scopes.NO_SCOPE, provider=Provider<org.slf4j.Logger>} 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,891 [  71747]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 3. InstanceBinding{key=Key[type=com.google.inject.Stage, annotation=[none]], source=[unknown source], instance=DEVELOPMENT} 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,891 [  71747]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 4. InstanceBinding{key=Key[type=org.codehaus.plexus.context.Context, annotation=[none]], source=org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$ContainerModule.configure(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:800), instance={plexus=org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer@290238e6}} 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,891 [  71747]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 5. InstanceBinding{key=Key[type=java.util.Map, annotation=@org.sonatype.inject.Parameters], source=org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$ContainerModule.configure(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:801), instance=null} 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,891 [  71747]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 6. InstanceBinding{key=Key[type=org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.MutableBeanLocator, annotation=[none]], source=org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$ContainerModule.configure(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:803), instance=org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.DefaultBeanLocator@47715323[Locked by thread RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]} 

6~235, omitted

2016-03-11 07:50:48,904 [  71760]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 235. ConstructorBinding{key=Key[type=org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecyclePluginResolver, annotation=[none]], source=ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null], scope=Scopes.SINGLETON} 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,904 [  71760]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -   236. ConstructorBinding{key=Key[type=org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleThreadedBuilder, annotation=[none]], source=ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null], scope=Scopes.SINGLETON} 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,904 [  71760]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 237. ConstructorBinding{key=Key[type=org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator, annotation=[none]], source=ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null], scope=Scopes.SINGLETON} 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,904 [  71760]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - -----[implicit bindings]------------------------------------------------------- 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,904 [  71760]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
2016-03-11 07:50:48,904 [  71760]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -  
2016-03-11 07:50:49,935 [  72791]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar
```

Comment: ps：System Version is OS X EI Capitan 10.11.3

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem with resetting the host name of my mac, which was set with blank like "Coderec's MBP".
The illegal host name caused this confusing problem.